# Eigen::SimplicialLDLT - Change from 3.3.9 to 3.4.0 for positive semi-definite matrices?

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen, solver, eigen3

I've recently updated my Eigen version from 3.3.9 to 3.4.0, using vcpkg for Windows. Running my program with the new version, I've encountered an error in solvability for the SimplicialLDLT method.

I'm using the solver to solve a sparse nonlinear least squares problem with the following squared positive semi-definite matrix C with a dense vector c.

```
C = [A'TA B'T;
     B 0]
```

In version 3.3.9, Eigen solves the sparse matrices correctly and my optimization routine worked well. With the new version, this somehow always ends in m_info: "NumericalIssue(1)", causing the solver not to do anything.

The compiler is MSVC v142, x64

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Using other solvers, such as the LU solvers from Eigen or SVQR from Cusolver, everything works fine but significantly slower than the former SimplicialLDLT implementation. Is this a known issue with the specific matrix structure and are there any ways to get the SimplicialLDLT to work again in Eigen 3.4.0?

Edit:
Here is a code to reproduce the error. The csv-matrix file is uploaded here:
https://easyupload.io/smf5tp:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>

Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> ReadSparseMatrix(const std::string& filename)
{
    // Open the file
    std::ifstream file(filename);
    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Unable to open file " + filename);
    }

    // Read in the matrix size
    std::string line;
    std::getline(file, line);
    std::stringstream lineStream(line);
    int rows, cols;
    char delimiter;
    lineStream >> rows >> delimiter >> cols;

    // Create the sparse matrix
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> matrix(rows, cols);

    // Read in each nonzero entry from the file
    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        std::stringstream lineStream(line);
        int row, col;
        double value;
        char delimiter;
        lineStream >> row >> delimiter >> col >> delimiter >> value;
        matrix.insert(row, col) = value;
    }

    // Finalize the sparse matrix
    matrix.makeCompressed();

    return matrix;
}

int main() {
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> sp_mat = ReadSparseMatrix("c_mat.csv");
    Eigen::SimplicialLDLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> solver_ldlt(sp_mat);

    if (solver_ldlt.info() != Eigen::Success)
        std::cerr << "Solver failed. Singular N Matrix?" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Solver successful!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is solved correctly if Eigen 3.3.9 and SimplicialLDLT is used, just as SparseLU with both 3.3.9 and 3.4.0.

Comment: Please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)